# Using jquery, How can i reference the internal input box that is coming from a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<ul class="tags tagit ui-widget-content">
   <li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
       <span class="tagit-label">Jersey City</span><a class="tagit-close"><span class="text-icon">×</span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="locationTag" value="Jersey City" style="display:none;">     
   </li>

   <li class="tagit-new">
      <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
      <input type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
   </li>
</ul>
```

and I would like to put some text into the inner input that is inside the LI with the "tagit-new" class (the one with class ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input)

What is the best way of referencing that input using jquery selector so i can add content into the val() method?  This is being generated from a jquery plugin so i can't add an Id attribute to it . .

The one thing that is unique around this input is the "tagit-new"  class

Comment: give it an id and then do $('#id').val('text');

Comment: @PatrickGeyer - as per the updated question. this html is being generated from an jquery plugin so i can't.  If i had the ability to find it to add the id attribute to it then i wouldn't have the issue iuen the first place ?)

Comment: Then do it by class... you said it was unique, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on wether or not you have other elements with the same class, but being as specific as one can be, you can do:

```
$('ul.tags.tagit.ui-widget-content li.tagit-new input.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete-input').val('some text');
```

or just give it a unique identifier (ID), which would be more efficient and easier.

Comment: i added another LI to show what it could look like in terms of other items having that class. the one thing that is unique is the "tagit-new" class

Comment: Then target whatever you need, this targets all the elements classes, and as long as they are the same as the classes in the example it should work, but if this is generated by a plugin, chances are that the classes aren't even there on pageload, and you'll have to wait until after the plugin does it's thing to target the elements.